# compile typescript in chatbot

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a chatbot I'm following a tutorial on youtube

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYuWse7GB9E
```

However at the end of the tutorial you build the typescript using the command Ctrl + Shift + b

my tsconfig.json file looks like this

```
{
    "conpileOnSave":true,
    "compileOptions":{
    "module":"commonjs",
    "target":"es6",
    "sourceMap":true,
    "declaration":false,
    "removeComments":true,
    "outDir":"./dist",
    "allowJs":true
    },
    "files":[
    "./lib/types.ts",
    "./lib/app.ts"
    ]
}
```

and my app.ts file looks like this

```
import { BotFrameworkAdapter, MemoryStorage,ConversationState } from "botbuilder";
import * as restify from "restify";
//import { ConfState } from "./types";

let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`${server.name} listening on ${server.url}`);
})

const adaptor = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

let conversationState;

const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);

//const conversationState = new ConversationState(new MemoryStorage());
adaptor.use(conversationState);

server.post("/api/messages",(req,res) => {
    adaptor.processActivity(req,res,async(context) =>{
    if(context.activity.type === "message") {
        const state = conversationState.get(context);
        await context.sendActivity(`you said ${context.activity.text}`);
    } else {
        await context.sendActivity(`${context.activity.type} event detected`);
    }
    })
});
```

my problem is that it builds, well doesn't have any errors but nothing is ever built into the "dist" folder so when I then run "node server.js" which contains this code

```
module.exports = require("./dist/app");
```

It throws an error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './dist/app'
```

Has anyone any idea what is wrong. I have changed the permissions on the dist folder to full but still nothing.

thanks

my complete source code can be found here

```
https://github.com/andrewslaughter/chatbot/tree/master/video2
```

Comment: try adding `"rootDir": "./lib"` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Added that, it has now created app.js and a types.js in the lib dir but noting in the dist dir